# Excel VBA will not close final workbook

Tags: excel

Final workbook in a chain of 4 workbook's open and closing each other will not close via VBA macro when run in the chain (but works fine when run alone and the others close fine).

I tried all these codes (which all work, when I open just one file, but not when its the last workbook). No errors or dialogue boxes pop up, it seems to complete smoothly in that sense, however the window remains open. No close action done.

```
Windows("WorkbookName.xlsm").Close

Workbooks("WorkbookName.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

If ActiveCell.Value = "Close this" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End If

Call WorkbookClose
```

(tried all three above in a separate sub and called it)

The process for this is pretty much along these lines.. 
Workbook opens and auto runs a private sub which calls a macro in the workbook via "Run MacroName" which does like open a CSV, resave as XLSX.

Opens them via

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _ (directory) (This works)
```

Then the main workbook is opened and follows these steps

ThisWorkbook > Private Sub > Calls macro

The macro called, closes the last workbook via:

```
Windows("WorkbookName.xlsm").Close 
'This works
```

Runs some simple code which opens another file, saves as XLSX, closes it. 
Opens another file which does the same thing i.e. auto runs and closes previous workbook, runs a bit of code, saves, opens another workbook which closes the last. However when it reaches the fourth workbook (the last one) it stops working. The code does not close that workbook.

Also to mention if I add any code after these lines, they execute. Its as if Excel just skips the close commands without error and keeps going until the end of the code.

```
Windows("WorkbookName.xlsm").Close

Workbooks("WorkbookName.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

If ActiveCell.Value = "Close this" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End If

Call WorkbookClose
```

No error messages pop up.

I just want the final workbook to close.

Comment: If its a small list of commands in the code, you can loop through the code step-by-step using the F8 function key. This often help you figure out the issue

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the Workbook with the running macro. perhaps you want `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Gangula - When I use F8 everything works perfect, and when I open it manually (its set to auto run) and it runs perfect (closes itself in end). The issue is when I open the previous wb which does its thing ending with code to open this workbook. Then this wb's code auto runs starting with closing the previous WB, and ending with closing itself. It fails to close itself only in this scenario but leaves the wb open and the code complete. So I cant get any error or find what is causing this code to fail.

Comment: Cybernetic - All three of those codes work to close it, but see the above notes. I also tried ActiveWorkbook as a 4th version of same action, still no luck. Something is preventing the wb from being closed without throwing an error.